# Are there any natural cases of direct translation of DNA to protein?

Tags: molecular-biology

I'm aware direct translation of DNA to protein (without the need for RNA) has been observed in test-tubes using e-coli. (Reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC219759/)
I wanted to know whether there have been any **natural** cases for this that have been observed. And suppose there aren't, would it be theoretically possible in a cellular environment?

Comment: Please provide a reference for your assertion. But in any case the answer is NO. Why do you think the complex system that exists developed?

Comment: I have edited the post to provide a reference.

Comment: OK. You should consider whether the technology used in that work over 50 years ago was able to demonstrate and compare it with your assertion.

Comment: I'm aware that RNA is of course an essential role in molecular biology for almost all complex systems as far as I know. Its importance to biology is unquestionable. However, the reason I asked this question in the first place was from reading Crick's Central Dogma of Biology article (https://cs.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs380/fall2012/CrickCentralDogma1970.pdf). In it, while he ruled any transfers from Protein to nucleic acids impossible, he argues that while there is no evidence for direct DNA to protein translation nor is it impossible either.

Comment: But that was 60 years ago. It’s of historical interest — no more. Do you realize how little was known at the time?

Comment: I seem to remember that paper coming up here in a previous question. Is there some person or source still churning it up? You might try to check. Otherwise I may respond with a history lesson sometime in the next few days.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006291X09009127?via%3Dihub  It cannot just be historical interest alone; this 2009 paper shows researchers attempted (though also failed) direct DNA to protein translation. Still, the abstract does mention "the question still remains whether or not DNA could be directly translated into protein".  So it cannot be of historical interest alone if a study in 2009 attempted this.  Surely it's still an open question? Although I suppose the evidence renders it very unlikely.

Comment: @neuro Why does it matter to you? What thing are you trying to get at by studying this? Even that 2009 paper is essentially throwing it away. It's an open question only because you cannot prove a negative scientifically. It's a possible, but low-probability poorly-supported alternative to an RNA-world hypothesis.

Comment: @BryanKrause  I was just curious. Central dogma of biology interests me. But yes, the overall consensus seems to be that in vivo dna to protein direct translation is highly unlikely, if not impossible.

Comment: Ah thanks for this @David . This post unintentionally seems to be a duplicate of that previous post. But your answer  on that post was what I was looking for anyhow. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Your post was expressed in different terms and had a different focus, but most of the problems around it are discussed there and in another post mentioned in a comment. Regarding The Central Dogma, I have an answer to a [question on that](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/crick-s-central-dogma-counter-cases), referencing the original 1956 formulation. 1956 — Transfer RNA wasn't discovered until 1965! What Crick was doing was emphasizing that you couldn't get back to NA from protein, but not ruling out other possibilities which might be possible in principle.